Matplotlib .contains method no longer works with updated environment
.contains method worked with matplotlib 3.4.3 and python 3.8.19
no longer works with updated environment.
The method returns a boolean and dictionary.
It is always returning False and empty dictionary even when the mouse is hovering over datapoint.
Migrated back to original environment with matplotlib version 3.4.3 and python version 3.8.19 to confirm the problem was caused by environment update.
Looked for related posts and dug through the matplotlib library to try to troubleshoot. Finally found an alternate method to create annotations, but I would like to know why the .contains method no longer works.
Minimal working example:
import sys
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import \
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    )

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Live Charts")
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.setCentralWidget(GraphWidget())

class GraphWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.prev_ind = None
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas()
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
        self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot()
        self.canvas.figure = self.fig

        x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
        y = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

        self.sc = self.ax.scatter(x,
                                  y,
                                  edgecolors='Midnightblue',
                                  color='cornflowerblue')

        self.annot = self.ax.annotate("", (x, y),
                                      annotation_clip=True,
                                      size=7, textcoords="offset points",
                                      bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                                      arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

        self.annot.set_visible(False)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.hover)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def hover(self, event):
        vis = self.annot.get_visible()
        if event.inaxes == self.ax:
            print("event: " + str(event))
            self.cont, self.ind = self.sc.contains(event)
            print("self.ind: " + str(self.ind))
            print("self.cont: " + str(self.cont))
            if self.cont:
                self.update_annot(self.ind)
                self.annot.set_visible(True)
                self.prev_ind = self.ind
                self.canvas.draw()
            else:
                if vis:
                    self.annot.set_visible(False)
                    self.prev_ind = None
                    self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showMaximized()
    window.activateWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Knowing to what version you did the update may help, but you should probably consider asking directly on matplotlib forums or check their bug report system.

Updated version of matplotlib is 3.8.

It seems like the problem is with the way I built my graph/class.
This post helped: How to make a matplotlib plot interactive in pyqt5
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import \
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    )

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Live Charts")
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.setCentralWidget(GraphWidget())


class GraphWidget(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.prev_ind = None
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self)

        self.x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
        self.y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot()
        self.ax.scatter(self.x, self.y)

        self.annot = self.ax.annotate("", (self.x, self.y),
                                      annotation_clip=True,
                                      size=7, textcoords="offset points",
                                      bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                                      arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

        self.annot.set_visible(False)
        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.hover)

        self.draw()

    def hover(self, event):
        vis = self.annot.get_visible()
        if event.inaxes == self.ax:
            self.cont, self.ind = self.ax.collections[0].contains(event)
            print("self.ind: " + str(self.ind))
            print("self.cont: " + str(self.cont))
            if (self.prev_ind is None or self.ind.values()
                    != self.prev_ind.values()):
                self.x_data = event.xdata
                self.y_data = event.ydata
                if self.cont:
                    self.update_annot(self.ind)
                    self.annot.set_visible(True)
                    self.prev_ind = self.ind
                    self.draw()
                else:
                    if vis:
                        self.annot.set_visible(False)
                        self.prev_ind = None
                        self.draw()
            else:
                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showMaximized()
    window.activateWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


